# How to check if someone in your address book has the app installed

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I am creating a mobile app and when users want to add another user, I need to check if the user in their address book actually has the app installed or not. Kind of like the big chat apps where it only shows you users from your address book/contact list that have the app installed.

How is this achieved? When you register does it upload all of your contacts to the server and then check against that list to see if that number also registered? I wouldn't think so because these apps are so fast when loading users you can message that it doesn't look like there is any call to the server, it is instant.

The part I don't understand is that if on my phone I have saved the persons number as 0111234567 that works when I call them or message then in an instant messenger.

But that format isn't what they would sign up with in the app, it would be something like +27 111234567

So, when searching the database how can it compare those 2 which aren't the same?

Comment: How long do you think a network request takes?  Especially when you can do it when the app loads, rather than when the page loads.  That's exactly how its done.

Comment: Okay, please see my edited question. It is regarding the format you save a contact and the format when that user registers, they could be different.

Comment: By writing some logic to normalize all phone numbers into one standard format, and comparing that.  There;s a standard for writing phone numbers that usually begins with + and the country code then goes on from there, that would probably be the normalized phone number format.

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought but not sure how that would be done. So, I would imagine that I take the number from my contact list and convert it into international format. But if I have contacts in different countries it would somehow have to pick up the country and convert accordingly.

Comment: Same way your phone does it when it makes a call.  If there's no country code, it assumes your SIM's country.  If there is one, it uses that.  If you had someone saved in a different country and didn't have a country code in there, it wasn't going to work anyway